# Google maps permission to use the location failed

Tags: android, permissions, maps

I am asking for permissions, when the app is firstly installed using this code:

```
 private void getLocationPermission() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            initMap();
            getDeviceLocation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                getDeviceLocation();
                //initialize our map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when it gets checked by `getLocationPermission` that I do not have the permission to use the location, the `permission alert dialog` pops up, and asks me if I `allow` it or not. But, if I press the `allow` option, in my `logcat` I get message `onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed`, as, according to my code, would mean I did not give access. The weird part is that if I reopen the activity using the map, the permissions work fine.

Comment: you are asking 2 permissions, don't do `return` from `if{}` if there is any single permission not granted, check for all. like if `grantResults == null` or `length == 0` than permission may not granted

Comment: Yes, now it's working properly. Thanks for info